# Is there any way to implement "Open in Safari" with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, deeplink

In iOS, Google app has "Open in Safari" option like below image. I would like to implement with JavaScript like that. Is it possible?

[image]

My JavaScript is to be run in a web browser on the mobile.

Comment: Is your JavaScript running in a web browser on a mobile or is it running in an iOS native app?

Comment: @Pang It is running in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

**To my knowledge, this is not possible**

The only way to trigger a specific app from a website is via its URI scheme *or* Universal Links. Safari doesn't support incoming Universal Links, and it doesn't have a specified URI scheme (other than `http` and `https`). This means if the app you're currently in is already handling `http` and `https` URLs (which it presumably is, if you're using it to display the page in the first place, there isn't much you can do with plain javascript.

This is a place where you need direct access to native app code.